# How do we get the URL of the current page in Selenium RC for C#?

Tags: c#, html, selenium-rc

I am trying to get the URL of the current page in Selenium RC for C#. I don't want to get the href attribute of an icon, as I want to use it to compare it with the URL, the icon redirects you too.

Answer (score 1):

say you have defined it as

```
         IWebDriver wb;
         wb = New FirefoxDriver();
         wb.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://gogoel.com");
```

then to get current url use

```
          String ptr=wb.Url;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Selenium RC instead of the Selenium Web Driver ?