# C# and selenium: Get current URL and store in a string

Tags: c#, selenium

I Need to get the current URL. Split that URL and store it in a string.
What I have tried is -

```
String urlSecondpart = this.getDriver().getCurrentUrl().Split("/a/")[1];
```

This opens a new url not the current URL

Comment: Can you please tell what you are getting currently? and what's your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we get the URL of the current page in Selenium RC for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569699/how-do-we-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-selenium-rc-for-c)

Comment: can you provide us with getDriver() implementation?

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate . It is pretty simple in java but in  c sharp I am not able to get the current URL and then I want to split. It is opening a new browser instead of giving the current URL. The current URL is random so we cannot do GoToUrl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the url of the current window using webdriver in selenium c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874765/can-i-get-the-url-of-the-current-window-using-webdriver-in-selenium-c)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something wrong in your code but you haven't posted enough for us to see the problem. Do some reading and create a 2 line script and make sure the basics are working.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String currentURL =  driver.Url;
```

If they aren't, you have something installed incorrectly or version mismatching. Fix that and try again. If it is working, you will have to debug your script by placing a breakpoint when the script starts and walking through your code until you find the problem.

Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially the last link on how to debug small programs.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using Firefox profile as an example

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

// todo: initialize your profile using firefoxProfile.SetPreference

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
string url = driver.Url; // get the current full URL
```

Then make use of standard string operation to extract what you want.

For the details in `SetPreference` and setting up a profile, please refer to http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: This is not working . It is not recognizing  getDriver().

Comment: I put `getDriver()` as that was from your code. I've modified and shown you the steps I used to access `getDriver()`.

Comment: This is not giving me the current URL.It is opening a new browser.

Comment: public IWebDriver getDriver(){
  return driver;
 }

Comment: @user3285912 as mentioned, you've to `setPreference`. What's your code on this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a static object of the driver once outside of the main method and within a class.

```
public class Test

{

 public static IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

 static void Main(string[] args) {

  // Here your code
  string url = driver.Url;

 }

}
```

It will give you an URL of the current page.